# URLSession dataTask / uploadTask splitting large uploads into multiple requests

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, upload, large-files

Hoping someone can shed some light on this behavior.

1. Large file (say 50mb+) needs to be uploaded to server
2. Uploading is split into multiple **requests**, not chunks in a single request ( see Charles image )
3. Using any of these all have the same behavior.

- `URLSession.shared.dataTask`
- `URLSession.shared.uploadTask`
- `URLSession.shared.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest:)`
- `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher`

4. Server is node / express, testing locally.

```
// Express server route
app.post('/save', (req, res, next) => {

   // Receives twice for the same upload
}
```

#### Example Attempt

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/octet-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    request.setValue("chunked", forHTTPHeaderField: "transfer-encoding")
    request.httpBodyStream = InputStream(data: package)
    let task = self.session.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: request)
    self.streamingTask = task
    task.resume()
```

---

Is this normal? It seems odd to me, and makes it difficult to put together the data at the end.
I've set various headers to see if that's what I'm missing, such as `Content-Length`, tried multiple encodings ( multipart/form, json ).

[image: Charles Image]

**Edit:**
Just discovered that `Content-Length` is a reserved header and cannot be manually set. But the content length is not being set to the size of the httpBody.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I suspected this was a question ripe for a face palm. The url system works as expected, but I was triggering through

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImage
```

which for anyone looking in the future might have its block called more than once if the first one it returns has the `PHImageResultIsDegradedKey` set to `1`.

[Apple Doc Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimageresultisdegradedkey)

This is what was causing the requests to **appear** like they were being split apart, but in reality it was submitting a thumbnail of an image and then the full size once it loaded.

The goose is caught, but it was a silly chase. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you should leave it as one upload request if possible and utilize background sessions to let the OS handle the upload for you.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1407496-background

Then you don't have to worry about one part failing to upload but others did, etc.  It also simplifies things for your server, it either gets the file or it doesn't.

Comment: I'm only sending one, but the urlsession system appears to be splitting it in two. :/